# How do I deal with null values in target variables in regression?

Tags: regression, data-transformation, missing-data

I'm trying to approximate a variable 'lag', measured in days until a certain event happens. My dataset is balanced in that, for half of the observations, 'lag' is not a number (ie. the event never happens).

How do I transform this variable in a way that doesn't introduce noise (ie. setting it to 0)?

Comment: You'll want to look into survival analysis methods taking into account right censoring. Also, why do exactly half the observations not have a completion time? Are you stopping data collection when that threshold is crossed?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Data collection is truncated at 30 days. Actually, the dataset has been balanced manually for testing purposes, but strictly, it has about one order of magnitude more null observations that non-null (for that particular variable)

Comment: This is actually a really good suggestion. If you want the accept, just post your comment as an answer and I'll close it.